# What did I do wrong with this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

**PROBLEM**

I have to compute this indefinite integral:
$$\int(2-x)^2\ln(4x)\,\,dx$$

---

**MY ATTEMPT**

So I did integration by parts:

$$\begin{matrix}
u=(2-x)^2 & dv=\ln(4x)\,\,dx\\
du=(2x-4)\,\,dx & v=\int\ln(4x)\\
\end{matrix}$$
$$\int\ln(4x)\,\,dx=\;\;?$$
$$\begin{matrix}
a=\ln(4x) & db=dx\\
da={1\over x}\,\,dx & b=x\\
\end{matrix}$$

$$\int\ln(4x)\,\,dx=x\ln(4x)-\int x\,\cdot\frac1x\,\,dx$$
$$\int\ln(4x)\,\,dx=x\ln(4x)-x$$
So because of that:
$$\int(2-x)^2\ln(4x)\,\,dx=(2-x)^2\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)-\int(2x-4)\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)\,\,dx$$
Now integrating by parts one more time:
$$\begin{matrix}
u=2x-4 & dv=\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)\,\,dx\\
du=2\,\,dx & v=\int\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)\,\,dx\\
\end{matrix}$$
$$\int\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)\,\,dx=\int x\ln(4x)\,\,dx\;-\int x\,\,dx$$
$$\begin{matrix}
a=\ln(4x) & db=x\,\,dx\\
da={1\over x}\,\,dx & b=\frac{x^2}{2}\\
\end{matrix}$$
$$\int x\ln(4x)\,\,dx=\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;-\int\frac{x^2}{2}\,\cdot\frac1x\,\,dx$$
$$\int x\ln(4x)\,\,dx=\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;-\int\frac x2\,\,dx$$
$$\int x\ln(4x)\,\,dx=\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{x^2}{4}$$
$$\int\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)\,\,dx=\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}$$
Finally, after all this mess, plugging in in the equation of the original integral:
$$\int(2-x)^2\ln(4x)\,\,dx=(2-x)^2\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)-\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^2}{2}+c$$
Now, I cleaned up this mess a little to give a nicer answer:
$$(2-x)^2\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)-\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^2}{2}+c$$
$$x(x^2-4x+4)\Big(\ln(4x)-1\Big)-\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^2}{2}+c$$
$$(x^3-4x^2+4x)\ln(4x)-x^2+4x-4-\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;+\frac34 x^2+c$$
$$(x^3-4x^2+4x)\ln(4x)-\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)-x^2+4x-4\;+\frac34 x^2+c$$
$$\boxed{\Big(x^3-\frac{9}{2}x^2+4x\Big)\ln(4x)-\frac{1}{4}x^2+4x-4+c}$$

---

**ANSWER FROM WOLFRAMALPHA**

WolframAlpha gives me a different answer:
$$\frac{1}{9}x\Big(-x^2+3(x^2-6x+12)\ln(4x)+9x-36\Big)+c$$
Even after rearranging the WA's answer, I get similar answer but the coefficients and other details don't match. I won't bother rearranging the WolframAlpha's answer here, but trust me, after putting it into similar form to my answer, it doesn't work.

---

**So what did I do wrong?**

Comment: You could have avoided a lot of this mess by using $u = \log{(4x)}$ instead, then you only get one IBP and a simple integral, the answers are related via the $+C$

Comment: Yep you're right :facepalm:Well, maybe next time

Comment: Indeed, though it is a nice exercise in integration to do it the way you've done it. Truly some nice practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to here

$$\int(2-x)^2\ln(4x)\,\,dx=(2-x)^2\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)-\int(2x-4)\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)\,\,dx$$

it seems to be correct but this

$$\int(2-x)^2\ln(4x)\,\,dx=(2-x)^2\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)-\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^2}{2}+c$$

seems not correct since you didn't considered the term

$$A=(2x-4)\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$

and also the calculation of this part $\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$ seems uncorrect indeed the integral should be

$$\int(2x-4)\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)\,\,dx=-\frac89x^3+3x^2+\frac23(x^3-3x^2)\ln (4x)$$

Let try to fix form here, since

$$\int\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)\,\,dx=\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{3x^2}{4}$$

we have that

$$\int(2x-4)\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)\,\,dx=\\
=(2x-4)\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{3x^2}{4}\right)-2\int\Big(\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{3x^2}{4}\Big)\,\,dx=\\
=(2x-4)\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{3x^2}{4}\right)+\frac{x^3}{2}-\int x^2\ln(4x)\,\,dx=\\
=(x^3-2x^2)\ln(4x)\;-(x^3-3x^2)-\frac13x^3\log (4x)+\frac19x^3=\\
-\frac89x^3+3x^2+\frac23(x^3-3x^2)\ln (4x)$$

Comment: That's right I lost the x term there, but it seems that the answer is still wrong, I probably did something wrong before rearranging :/

Comment: Your answer still didn't work, I found out what is wrong and posted my own answer. Look into it if you're interested.

Comment: It seems you have edited your answer, but it was different before. I didn't see the edit so I posted my own answer

Comment: @KKZiomek Sorry I was working on that, yes that's right your "big" mistake was in the second integration by parts. Really a messy integral, it takes time to write down in teX.

Comment: I'll still accept your answer because to be fair you edited the post spotting the mistake 6 minutes before me :)

Comment: @KKZiomek Thanks, nice work! Bye

Answer (score 2):

**WHAT I DID WRONG**

I figured out what I did wrong. I didn't finish the third integration by parts in my work. I ended up doing:
$$\int(2-x)^2\ln(4x)\,\,dx=(2-x)^2\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)-\int\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)\,\,dx$$
Instead of this:
$$\int(2-x)^2\ln(4x)\,\,dx=(2-x)^2\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)-\int(2x-4)\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)\,\,dx$$
I didn't drop the $(2x-4)$, it's there, in the third integration by parts, I just forgot to finish the integration by parts, and wrongly replaced $\int(2x-4)\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)\,\,dx$ with $\int\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)\,\,dx$.

---

**The real answer should've been:**
$$(2-x)^2\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)-(2x-4)\Bigg(\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}\Bigg)+2\int\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{3}{4}x^2\,\,dx$$
We have another integration by parts (sad face):
$$\begin{matrix}
u=ln(4x) & dv=\frac{x^2}{2}\,\,dx\\
du=\frac1x\,\,dx & v=\frac{x^3}{6}\\
\end{matrix}$$
$$\int\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\,\,dx=\frac{x^3}{6}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{x^3}{18}$$
$$\int\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{3}{4}x^2\,\,dx=\frac{x^3}{6}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{x^3}{18}-\frac{x^3}{4}$$
This gets us:
$$(2-x)^2\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)-(2x-4)\Bigg(\frac{x^2}{2}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}\Bigg)+\frac{x^3}{3}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{x^3}{9}-\frac{x^3}{2}+c$$
Now rearranging this to get a nice answer:
$$(2-x)^2\Big(x\ln(4x)-x\Big)-(x-2)\Bigg(x^2\ln(4x)\;-\frac{x^2}{2}-x^2\Bigg)+\frac{x^3}{3}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{11}{18}x^3+c$$
$$x(x^2-4x+4)\Big(\ln(4x)-1\Big)-(x-2)\Bigg(x^2\ln(4x)\;-\frac{3}{2}x^2\Bigg)+\frac{x^3}{3}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{11}{18}x^3+c$$
$$(x^3-4x^2+4x)\ln(4x)-(x^3-4x^2+4x)-(x^3-2x^2)\Big(\ln(4x)\;-\frac{3}{2}\Big)+\frac{x^3}{3}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{11}{18}x^3+c$$
$$(-2x^2+4x)\ln(4x)-(x^3-4x^2+4x)+\frac{3}{2}(x^3-2x^2)+\frac{x^3}{3}\ln(4x)\;-\frac{11}{18}x^3+c$$
$$\Big(\frac13x^3-2x^2+4x\Big)\ln(4x)-(x^3-4x^2+4x)+\frac{3}{2}(x^3-2x^2)-\frac{11}{18}x^3+c$$
$$\Big(\frac13x^3-2x^2+4x\Big)\ln(4x)+\frac12x^3+x^2-4x-\frac{11}{18}x^3+c$$
$$\boxed{\Big(\frac13x^3-2x^2+4x\Big)\ln(4x)-\frac19x^3+x^2-4x+c}$$

---

After rearranging the WolframAlpha's answer, the two answers match, so this one is correct. Wow, what a messy integral.